# masscan. how to configure Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, nmap

I've set this in my `sysctl.conf`:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=268435456
```

Because, this border `16,777,216` achieved very quick.

Also, I've decrease timeouts:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=54000
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
./masscan 0.0.0.0/0 -p 80 --rate 500000 --exclude exclude.conf -oG output.txt
```

I want to increase the rate from `500,000` to `5,000,000`. I have 100 mbps.

I'm trying to change the rate from `100,000` to upper borders.

Nevertheless, my `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count` doesn't grow more than `1,609,909`. And remaining time 73 hours 20 minutes, with rate 100k or 500k, it doesn't matter.

Other settings:

```
net.core.rmem_default = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 4194304
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_max = 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 65536 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 4194304
```

Seems like something else needs to be increased. Looks like somewhere insufficient memory or record fields.

How do I find the bottle neck?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems you are wanting to exceed the 1.6 million packets-per-second limitation by increasing the `--rate` to 5,000,000.

According to the masscan author from [this site](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan/blob/master/README.md):

```
On Linux (no virtualization) it'll do 1.6 million packets-per-second.

By default, the rate is set to 100 packets/second. To increase the rate to a million use something like --rate 1000000.
```